# Will Database omit incoming request since it is busy?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, relational-database

In my application I have implemented a method to get favourits of particular user. If the user is a new one there will not be a entry in the table.If so I add default favourtis to the table. Code is shown below.

```
 public String getUserFavourits(String username) {
 String s = "SELECT FAVOURITS FROM USERFAVOURITS WHERE USERID='" +
        username.trim() + "'";
    String a = "";
    Statement stm = null;
    ResultSet reset = null;
    DatabaseConnectionHandler handler = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
      handler = DatabaseConnectionHandler.getInstance();
      conn = handler.getConnection();
      stm = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
      reset = stm.executeQuery(s);
      if (reset.next()) {
        a = reset.getString("FAVOURITS").toString();
      }
      reset.close();
      stm.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      try {
        handler.returnConnectionToPool(conn);

        if (stm != null) {
          stm.close();
        }
        if (reset != null) {
          reset.close();
        }
      }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
      a = updateNewUserFav(username);
    }
    return a;
  }
```

You can see that after the Finally block updateNewUserFav(username) method is use to insert default favourits in to table. Normally users are forced to change this in their first login.
My problem is many users have complain me about they hava lost their customized favourits and default has get loaded in their login. When I go through the code I notice that it can only happen if exception occured in the try block. When I debug code works fine. Is this can be coused at time when DB is busy? 
 Normally there are more than  1000 concurrent user in the system. Since it is real time application there will be huge number a of request comming to the Database(DB is Oracle).

Can some one pls explain.

Comment: You should return the connection to the pool _after_ `stm` and `reset` are closed. Probably not the problem though.

Comment: Hi Ganuke,

What will happen if there is an exception thrown while checking (a.equalsIgnoreCase("")?
I was just thinking that there is a possibility of String a being null so you should be checking a==null as well.

Comment: You should also do proper logging of exceptions. Otherwise if something is breaking you'll never easily find it out.

Comment: An ACID database does not omit requests -- all queries on a database are queued, and use isolation levels to jump position.  As long as the query is received, the database will execute it.

Comment: Do any of your usernames have apostrophes?  You should use bind variables to prevent SQL injection and to improve performance.

Comment: @ jonearles I changed the code and used prepared statements to improve the performance.. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Clean up your code. This is not reasonable code. Why do you need "default" favourites (separate to the fact that your handling of then has a legacy) ?

Comment: @OMG. The ACID is specified in the Transaction (the Db supports it), and there ain't no Transactions here, just SELECTs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, use jonearles suggestion about bind variables. If a lot of your code is like this, with 1000 concurrent users, I'd hate to think what performance is like.

Secondly, if it is busy then there is a chance of time-outs. As you say, if an exception is encountered then it falls back to the "updateNewUserFav"

Really, it should only call that if NO exception is raised.
If an exception is raised, the function should fail. The current code is similar to

```
"TURN THE IGNITION KEY TO START THE CAR"
"IF THERE IS A PROBLEM, RING GARAGE AND BOOK APPOINTMENT"
"PUT CAR INTO GEAR AND RELEASE HAND_BRAKE"
```

You really only want to release the hand-brake once the car has successfully started, otherwise you'll end up rolling down the hill until the sudden stop at the end (often involving an expensive CRUNCH sound).

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestions. I'll do in that way. What if I recursively call this method if there is an exception. I can do that calling the getUserFavourits(username) method inside tha catch block.Is it ok..? Will it be a solution for time-outs?

Comment: If there is an exception, then determine the SQLCODE of that eception. If it is something you know how to deal with (eg timeout), deal with it (eg retry). Otherwise log it and raise it up, even if it eventually gets to the client with a "Request could not be satisfied, contact support".